# Creating a Save-able "Project" for C#

Tags: c#, database, system.data.sqlite

I am working on a project for visualizing large specialized datasets.

A "Project" consists of two large datasets (that are imported from XLS or CSV) and several other settings and smaller tables.  We were planning to store those tables in SQLite (for ease of access).

We would like to allow the users to save a "Project" so they do not need to load the CSV and XLS files again. We would also like to prevent users who get the project file later from tampering with the data. We want managers to be able to create a "Project" file and pass it to other employees (so they can use the visualized data in presentations, but they can not modify it).  The program already has the access control built in.

What suggestions do people have about creating this type of "Project" file, preferably based around a SQLite database.

**Note:** I am asking for advice here because it is impossible to Google for C# and Project. You get Visual Studio how-to results.

**Clarification:** Imagine this a if you opened Microsoft Word (or OpenOffice Write if your prefer). You can create open and save a "project". You can send a "project" to someone else who has the program.  I would like the "project" file not to be usable in a different SQLite client (for data security).

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a centralised database? As opposed to passing physical files around.

Comment: Yes. The users are not network connected. We do not want to make them install a database server and this application on every machine.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I immagine you can not put centralized database on keydrive or send via mail to your boss. Can not say to them to install SQL server only because the program works in that way.

Comment: @Tigran No need to teach people how to suck eggs, I am well aware of potential reasons why. None of them were stated in the question and the question is too broad so these comments are required. And for reference, you can put a centralised database on a keydrive if you detach it.

Comment: I have been adding clarifications.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: in your comment you ask about the reasons centralized DB can not be suitable, and I just reply on it. I'm not going to teach you anything. "Project" by itself (may be based on VS project concept) gave me a hint/idea about what OP searching for. It's just my opinion. Sorry, if I offend you in some way.

Comment: @yakatz I just noticed your amended comment... a centralised database wouldn't mean a database server on every machine. It would mean one database centrally that each instance of the application could connect to. It's a fairly stock and trade setup.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth As I said, they have no network connection.

Comment: @yakatz I know, I was just correcting your earlier incorrect observation. Are you also saying you don't want them to install the application on every machine, but want them to be able to open the file on every machine?

Comment: My program can be run off a flash drive. I do not want them to have to install MS SQL or MySQL and then import/attach the database, then use the program, then drop the database. When the computer is restarted, it is automatically reformatted (a paranoid bunch), so they would need to install the server again. That would not be very user friendly.

Comment: @yakatz I was not seriously suggesting it, but people are being pedantic so I decided to be the same. If you want my opinion, you should just serialize the stuff to disc and move on with your life, there are more important requirements to worry about than files - for example, how are you going to decide who is who when you make it read-only for everyone other than the original author. There is also the issue that none of these requirements are user friendly... copying files all over the place as opposed to just logging in and seeing it all?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth "There is also the issue that none of these requirements are user friendly... copying files all over the place as opposed to just logging in and seeing it all?" We have no choice. Nothing can be saved on the client's computer. Between each use, it is reformatted.

Comment: These sound like the requirements of people who don't understand networks or security, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say there is a *any* kind of template or *common* structure for those kind of things. Your structure is already good by itself. You may have not only data information, but also `meta-information` inside database file, specifying (say) *user name*, *data last changed*, *comments*, whatever to make your `project/doc file` more comprehencive and full of information, keeping constant attention on *memory footprint*, cause it would be very nice to have a possibility to pass that file to someone by *key-drive* or send by *e-mail*.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not create a table that has a series of BLOB data types (for documents) and a read_only boolean field. If you don't know how many docs there will be you need to enter another table called document that links to the project table!

Comment: That would mean parsing the XLS and CSV files again every time that the project is loaded. We are already storing them in SQLite tables. I want to know how to secure the application and if anyone has experience with things like saved projects.

Comment: @yakatz "Saved projects" is just a name you've given something, I doubt anyone will have experience with it.